# Python: Grouping by time interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

I'm using python 3.6.5 and a datetime.time object for the index

```
print(sum_by_time)

           Trips
  Time

00:00:00    10
01:00:00    10
02:00:00    10
03:00:00    10
04:00:00    20
05:00:00    20
06:00:00    20
07:00:00    20
08:00:00    30
09:00:00    30
10:00:00    30
11:00:00    30
```

How can I group this dataframe by time interval to get something like this:

```
                         Trips
       Time    

00:00:00 - 03:00:00        40
04:00:00 - 07:00:00        80
08:00:00 - 11:00:00       120
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need convert index values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index.astype(str))

df = df.resample('4H').sum()
print (df)
          Trips
00:00:00     40
04:00:00     80
08:00:00    120
```

EDIT:

For your format need:

```
df['d'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.astype(str))

df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='4H', key='d')).agg({'Trips':'sum', 'd':['first','last']})
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df = df.set_index(df['d_first'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S') + ' - ' + df['d_last'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))[['Trips_sum']]
print (df)
                     Trips_sum
00:00:00 - 03:00:00         40
04:00:00 - 07:00:00         80
08:00:00 - 11:00:00        120
```

Comment: You beat me to it! This is what I came up with! Just for future visitors, you can use 'H' for hour, 'T' for minute and 'M' for month time bins.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Any idea on how to make the index reflect the time intervals? i.e. instead of 00:00:00 write 00:00:00 - 03:00:00

Comment: @Jad - Added solution, please check it.

Comment: a different way to extract the information for the time spans, could be to use `to_period` on the index and use `start_time`and `end_time`. Then one doesn't need to parse the time string again.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 - Good idea, thanks. I try implement it.

Comment: How to without the pandas?